# Continuous data update via pouchdb query

Tags: ionic2, pouchdb, angular2-observables

i have a pouchdb database with a number of views setup that i query whenever i need data. I am using observables to handle the querying. However i have to refresh the interface to view any data changes in the database. Is there any way i can have these data changes read directly by the observable ? My code is as:-

**home.ts**

```
 this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe((posts) => {

      this.posts = posts.rows.map(row => {
        console.log(row.value);
        return row.value;
      });

    });
```

**posts.ts**

```
  getPosts(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.db.query('app/inputs'));
  }
```

Comment: You better use some event-drive model layer (such as Firebase) or use some architecture for this, such as flux or redux.

Comment: In this joshmorony tutorial (https://www.joshmorony.com/offline-syncing-in-ionic-2-with-pouchdb-couchdb/) he uses the   `this.db.changes({live: true, since: 'now', include_docs:true}).on('change', (change) => {
        this.handleChange(change);
      }); ` to handle data changes but i need this to work for the db.query

Comment: You could also try [ReactJS + MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use `db.changes` with your view, so that you'll only get events for view related changes:

```
db.changes({
  filter: '_view',
  view: 'app/inputs',
  live: true,
  since: 'now',
  include_docs:true
}).on('change', (change) => { this.handleChange(change); });
```

See the filtered changes section on [PouchDB docs](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#changes) for a more detailed explanation on this.

Comment: Thanks for that, the db.changes does offer the changes however the returned promise doesnot have these changes so they are not reflected on on the interface. Actually it only shows the changes the first time. How can i make every change to reflect on the interface. This is hpw i return the results from the service `return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.db.query('app/inputs').then(res => {`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, what I meant is you can use the code you mentioned before `this.db.changes({live: true, since: 'now', include_docs:true}).on('change', (change) => { doSomethingOnChange(change); });` with the `filter` and `view` options, so that `doSomethingOnChange` is only called when there are changes in a doc belonging to your view. 

To get all view docs as part of the `changes` feed response, what you can do is to call `this.db.query('app/inputs')` inside `doSomethingOnChange`. See an example of that [here](https://pouchdb.com/2015/02/28/efficiently-managing-ui-state-in-pouchdb.html).

Comment: I updated the code in the answer with what I mentioned in the previous comment to make it more clear.

The previous [link](https://pouchdb.com/2015/02/28/efficiently-managing-ui-state-in-pouchdb.html) also mentions ways of updating the UI on response to database changes in a more efficient way, maybe that can be helpful too?

Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with Observables, so I am not completely sure if this solution works with them.

Comment: I have shared a gist pliz checkout the code and help me out [gist](https://gist.github.com/wizlif/36c47e8c1fc7479a6a3c3ace37dc4973)

Comment: Not very familiar with ionic or with what you're trying to do but I think you can call `db.changes({..}).on('change', updatePosts)` within the constructor and then in `updatePosts` do `getPosts.then( posts => this.posts = posts)`?

Comment: Sorry for the dalayed reply, the issue is the promise only gives me an update the first time, while the rest of the times it doesn't i don't know why that would happen

Comment: That makes sense, you can use the changes feed as a [single-shot](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#single-shot) operation: only one call, works with promises, but will only run once, or continuously: passing the option `live: true`, where you can subscribe to events to be notified of all changes continuously (`on('change')`). This mode doesn't work with promises though.
If you want to be notified of all changes you have to use the second one and do something when the `change` event is fired.

Comment: Or you can use the promise version and make sure to run it repeatedly yourself with `setInterval` or similar?

Comment: ok that makes sense, i think i'll move the`on('change')` from the promise and get rid of the promise

Comment: I also think setInterval is not a good idea since it can run unnecessary code and also be idle when actually required to run